# Deferring- or Deferred- pattern in spring security framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Recently, I research about spring security. There are some classes and methods named with `Deferring-` and `Deferred-`.

For examples

- DeferredSecurityContext
- SupplierDeferredSecurityContext
- DeferringObservationReactiveAuthorizationManager
- DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager

and so on.

The common pattern of the classes or methods uses `Supplier` functional interface and get object from supplier function. Like this.

```java
final class DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager<T> implements AuthorizationManager<T> {

    private final Supplier<AuthorizationManager<T>> delegate;

    DeferringObservationAuthorizationManager(ObjectProvider<ObservationRegistry> provider, AuthorizationManager<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = SingletonSupplier.of(() -> {
            ObservationRegistry registry = (ObservationRegistry)provider.getIfAvailable(() -> {
                return ObservationRegistry.NOOP;
            });
            return (AuthorizationManager)(registry.isNoop() ? delegate : new ObservationAuthorizationManager(registry, delegate));
        });
    }

    public AuthorizationDecision check(Supplier<Authentication> authentication, T object) {
        return ((AuthorizationManager)this.delegate.get()).check(authentication, object);
    }
}
```

```java
public class HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository implements SecurityContextRepository {

    // ...
    
    public DeferredSecurityContext loadDeferredContext(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Supplier<SecurityContext> supplier = () -> {
            return this.readSecurityContextFromSession(request.getSession(false));
        };
        return new SupplierDeferredSecurityContext(supplier, this.securityContextHolderStrategy);
    }
}


final class SupplierDeferredSecurityContext implements DeferredSecurityContext {

    private final Supplier<SecurityContext> supplier;

    // ...

    public SecurityContext get() {
        this.init();
        return this.securityContext;
    }

    public boolean isGenerated() {
        this.init();
        return this.missingContext;
    }

    private void init() {
        if (this.securityContext == null) {
            this.securityContext = (SecurityContext)this.supplier.get();
            this.missingContext = this.securityContext == null;
            if (this.missingContext) {
                this.securityContext = this.strategy.createEmptyContext();
                if (logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                    logger.trace(LogMessage.format("Created %s", this.securityContext));
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm curious about this pattern. Why do not use instance directly? Are there benefits when we contain object in lambda function and defer to use?

- What is the purpose of this pattern?
- What do we get benefits from this pattern?
- Are there good examples to understand about this pattern's benefits or solve some problems?

Please, let me know. Thanks.

Comment: It only accesses the actual objects until needed, the Deferred part. Which is also the benefit which delays access to (heavy) objects until the moment it is actually needed. If it isn't strictly needed it won't be accessed.

Comment: exactly as pointed out in the previous comment. You dont load in the object until the first request of the object. You deferr the creation until later. Its to avoid the server from at startup loading in a bunch of things that is never used.

Comment: Thanks, your comments help to understand. Is there any relationship of reactive programming or asynchronously working?

Answer (score 0):

Deffering (postponing) the creation of resources is a pattern that is used for optimizing code into not creating a resource until it is explicitly requested for.

So the code you have presented does not crate a `SecurityCContext` until it is explicitly asked for, then and only then is it initially created. The same goes for the `ObservationRegistry` in your other example.

This comes with a small one time runtime cost, but the benefits are for instance shorter startup times for the server.